# another table is not created

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am developing an android app in which I am using the SQLite database. Now when I create two tables simultaneously only one first table gets created. I have created a class in which I extend SQLiteOpenHelper

Following is the code inside the databsehelper class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,fullname TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT)");
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME2+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,trid TEXT,email TEXT,description TEXT,image BLOB)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do to create the second table in the database

Comment: Did you change the version of the database?

Comment: no I have not changed the version it is 1

Comment: Change it to 2 so onUpgrade() is called.

Comment: Thanks it worked...